# Spring application context - FactoryBean.getObject() called before FactoryBean initialized

Tags: java, spring, applicationcontext

I'm experiencing some wierd problems where `FactoryBean.getObject()` is being called before the `FactoryBean` is initialized. I've created a small sample which displays some wierdness. It's not the exact issue I'm seeing with my larger application but I think it's related.

This is likely caused by a circular reference where

- `node1` references `node2`
- and `node2` references `node1`

I'm using spring version `4.2.4.RELEASE`

SpringTestContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<beans
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd"
>
    <bean id="node1" class="com.hsbc.gbm.dsl.dtm.test.SpringTest$NodeFactory">
        <property name="next" ref="node2" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="node2" class="com.hsbc.gbm.dsl.dtm.test.SpringTest$NodeFactory">
        <property name="prev" ref="node1" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

SpringTest.java

```
public class SpringTest {
    public static class Node {
        private final Node next;
        private final Node prev;
        public Node(Node prev, Node next) {
            super();
            this.prev = prev;
            this.next = next;
        }
    }

    public static class NodeFactory implements FactoryBean<Node>, BeanNameAware, ApplicationContextAware, InitializingBean {
        private Node next;
        private Node prev;
        private String beanName;
        private Node node;
        private ApplicationContext applicationContext;
        private boolean initialized;

        public void setNext(Node next) {
            this.next = next;
        }

        public void setPrev(Node prev) {
            this.prev = prev;
        }

        @Override
        public void setBeanName(String beanName) {
            this.beanName = beanName;
        }

        @Override
        public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
            this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
        }

        @Override
        public Class<?> getObjectType() {
            return Node.class;
        }

        @Override
        public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
            node = new Node(prev, next);
            initialized = true;
        }

        @Override
        public Node getObject() {
            System.out.println(String.format("NodeFactory: getObject() beanName=%s, initialized=%s, applicationContext=%s", 
                beanName, initialized, applicationContext));

            if (!initialized) {
                throw new RuntimeException("NodeFactory not initialized before getObject() for " + beanName);
            }
            return node;
        }

        public boolean isSingleton() {
            return true;
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        ClassPathXmlApplicationContext appContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("com/hsbc/gbm/dsl/dtm/test/SpringTestContext.xml");
        appContext.start();
    }
}
```

Output

```
NodeFactory: getObject() beanName=null, initialized=false, applicationContext=null
```

Exception

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: NodeFactory not initialized before getObject() for null
    at com.foo.SpringTest$NodeFactory.getObject(SpringTest.java:74)
    at com.foo.SpringTest$NodeFactory.getObject(SpringTest.java:1)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:168)
    ... 53 more
```

Full Trace

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'node1' defined in class path resource [com/foo/SpringTestContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'node2' while setting bean property 'next'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'node2' defined in class path resource [com/foo/SpringTestContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'node1' while setting bean property 'prev'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'node1': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: NodeFactory not initialized before getObject() for null
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:359)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1481)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1226)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:753)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at com.foo.SpringTest.test(SpringTest.java:117)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'node2' defined in class path resource [com/foo/SpringTestContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'node1' while setting bean property 'prev'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'node1': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: NodeFactory not initialized before getObject() for null
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:359)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1481)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1226)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:351)
    ... 38 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'node1': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: NodeFactory not initialized before getObject() for null
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:175)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:127)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getObjectForBeanInstance(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1585)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:254)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:351)
    ... 48 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: NodeFactory not initialized before getObject() for null
    at com.foo.SpringTest$NodeFactory.getObject(SpringTest.java:74)
    at com.foo.SpringTest$NodeFactory.getObject(SpringTest.java:1)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:168)
    ... 53 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone finding the same issue, I solved this by removing the circular dependency. I did this by setting a String instead of a `Node` for the `prev` property.

Eg:

```
    public static class NodeFactory implements FactoryBean<Node>, ... {
        private Node next;
        private String prevBeanId;
        ...
    }
```

XML

```
<bean id="node2" class="com.hsbc.gbm.dsl.dtm.test.SpringTest$NodeFactory">
    <property name="prevBeanId" value="node1" />
</bean>
```

I would have expected Spring to have thrown some form of `CircularReferenceException` rather than calling `Factory.getObject()` before it's initialized.

In my real application, the circular reference was harder to see as there were many beans involved in the circle rather than the two in the example test case.